# How to turn APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01 into a single string?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I gather that `APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01` is an array, and I want to store it in my database. The only way I know of is to transform it into a varchar2 delimited string. I tried to use the `TABLE_TO_STRING` function: `APEX_UTIL.TABLE_TO_STRING(APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01)` but this code gives the error "APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01 is of wrong type". Also oracle documentation says the function is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

`APEX_UTIL.TABLE_TO_STRING` works fine for me. I added the following line in a page process that processes a report with `APEX_ITEM` columns and it (1) compiles fine and (2) shows the correct output in the debug messages:

```
apex_debug.info('kl debug'||APEX_UTIL.TABLE_TO_STRING(APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01));
```

The data type of `APEX_APPLICATION.G_F01` is `sys.dbms_sql.varchar2a` which is defined as `TYPE VARCHAR2A IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(32767) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;`

On a side note: why would you want to store an array converted to a string in a column ? Working with data that is stored in colon separated strings is an absolute pain. Just loop through the array and store the individual values

Comment: "On a side note: why would you want to store an array converted to a string in a column ? Working with data that is stored in colon separated strings is an absolute pain. Just loop through the array and store the individual values" I know. Why doesn't oracle apex allow the creation of a table column of type array? I could create a separate table for each array, but I don't want to add 50 new tables to the database, especially since these tables will be constantly visible for the whole Apex instance instead of just contained to just the app that needs them.

Comment: Up to you to figure out what the best way is to implement your requirement. Storing a string with separated values is creating a lot of work for you or any other developers in your team going forward and it will not perform or scale well.